# Implement Filter and Search in Backend Module of own Extension

Tags: typo3

I have no idea how I have to improve my listview in the backend module with a search or a filter (for only the records in the folder). That's why I don't have any code to show.

I actually have a list of all records and now I have to optimize this view for the administrator. This means I'd like to search over some columns and a filter to show only the records with the selected categorie from the dropdown.

I hope that someone can give me a hint, link or example how to realize something like that. I think it is a general thing how I can manipulate or integrate own php scripts or whatever.

Thanks for your help guys

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an filter method to you repository. Submit the form of filters to your index action an instead of `$this->myRepository->fetchAll()` make an function with filter: `$this->myRepository->fetchByFilter($categorie)`.

In your repository class it looks something like that:

```
function fetchByFilter($categorie) {
  $query = $this->createQuery();

  $matching = [
    $query->containts('categories', $categorie)
  ];

  return $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($matching))->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be such feature soon in the TYPO3 core (version 8.x), however doing such thing is not really easy.

An easier approach would be to use a custom backend module and render the content of the list module there again including the filter. You can take a look how I do it with the TYPO3 extension `news`since version 5.0.

- The contoller: https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Classes/Controller/AdministrationController.php
- Adding the filter for the record list: https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Classes/Hooks/Backend/RecordListQueryHook8.php#L76

Hope that helps!